# How Do I implement chrome like binary autoupdating on my application?

Tags: auto-update

I have created small binary app and I would like it to autoupdate completely automatically, how do I do that ?

Its a huge app and I do not want to download-and-unzip the whole folder like I am doing right now, but I would like to do it binary+diff update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Google has open-sourced its auto updater for Windows. It's called Omaha and hosted on Google code [here](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/).